# Encrypt VPS of Tor service

Tags: vps

I was thinking of a way to encrypt the content of the VPS on which a Tor service runs. I would buy two VPS servers anonymously using crypto. The two VPS-servers will come from different hosting providers located in different countries.

On the first VPS (Storage) I will create a empty file of e.g 100GB. I will make this file accessible by using SSHFS.
On the second VPS (Tor service) I will mount the file on the first VPS using LUKS. By using LUKS I can create an encrypted file-system of 100GB using the file from the storage VPS.

This way the provider of the storage VPS can only see encrypted garbage. And while the provider of the Tor service VPS has the LUKS to view the content, it cannot easily access the content because it being on another VPS.

Is this an advantage or no?

Answer (score 0):

Good idea, but keep in mind, that VPS is a *virtualized* slice of machine, so it's memory can be inspected by the hypervisor's owner - and the encryption key can be extracted seamlessly. Unless AMD SEV with attestation is used. So - the right way is to use a dedicated box for it